# Como contar e fazer a mudança em todos os ElementID

Tags: javascript

O que este código permite é modificar o valor do campo de 0.00 para o valor pretendido, mesmo que seja 2, ele substitui para 2.00.

O meu problema é que ele apenas substitui de 1 INPUT, se tiver 2 INPUTS com o mesmo ID ele so modifica 1.

Como faço para que modifique em todos com o mesmo Elmt ID.

```
<script>

document.getElementById('currency').onblur = function (){    
    //number-format the user input
    this.value = parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,/g, ''))
                    .toFixed(2)
                    .toString()
                    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '.');
    //set the numeric value to a number input
    document.getElementById('number').value = this.value.replace(/,/g, '')
}
```

Comment: Se você  vai ter mais um input então sugiro usar uma class para que não tenha dois elementos com o mesmo id.

Comment: como assim? o que pretendo é localizar todos os ID iguais e modificalos...

Comment: @John não é possível. Você pode até ter vários *inputs* com o mesmo *ID*, mas o JavaScript irá considerar apenas um deles.

Comment: você até pode selecionar todos os elementos com o mesmo id dessa forma: document.querySelectorAll("#id");

Comment: nao funciona. eu substitui por isso document.querySelectorAll('#currency').onblur =function (){  e nada

Comment: Usando o meu codigo, consegue me ajudar a por direito?

Comment: ok, vou ver o que consigo fazer

Comment: se a resposta não resolver seu problema edite sua questão inserindo também o trecho html, para que eu possa entender melhor a estrutura da sua pagina

Comment: Brotherzinho, um id é como um CPF, cada um tem o seu **único**. Se vc está usando id's iguais em mais de um elemento, é sinal de que vc precisa aprender HTML. Já pensou se mais de uma pessoa tivesse o mesmo CPF, que inferno que não iria ser? :D

Answer (score -2, accepted):

usando o getElementById("id") ele ira retornar somente o primeiro elemento com o id, então para selecionar todos os elementos com mesmo id podemos utilizar o querySelectorAll("#id"), que nos retornara todos os elementos com aquele id.

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll("#currency");
```

depois de selecionar todos os elementos podemos usar o forEach para adicionar o evento em cada elemento dessa forma:

```
   elements.forEach(el => {
        el.onblur = () => {
            //number-format the user input
            el.value = parseFloat(el.value.replace(/,/g, ''))
                .toFixed(2)
                .toString()
                .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '.');
            //set the numeric value to a number input
            el.value = el.value.replace(/,/g, '');
        };
    });
```

lembrando que não é recomendável ter mais de um elemento com o mesmo id em um arquivo html, acredito que você poderia identificar os elementos utilizando uma class e obtendo os elementos dessa forma:

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".currency");
```

Assim você poderia passar um forEach em elements da mesma forma.

html usado para os testes:

```
<td>
    <tr>
        <input name='product_cost[]' placeholder='0.00' class='currency' type='text' class='form-control'
            placeholder='0.00' required>
    </tr>

</td>
<td>
    <input name='product_pvp[]' placeholder='0.00' class='currency' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='0.00'
        required>
</td>
<td>
    <input name='product_pvp[]' placeholder='0.00' class='currency' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='0.00'
        required>
</td>
<td>
    <input name='product_pvp[]' placeholder='0.00' class='currency' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='0.00'
        required>
</td>
```

Comment: mesmo assim, continua a nao dar

Comment: <td><input name='product_cost[]' placeholder='0.00' id='currency' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='0.00' required></td>
                                    <td><input name='product_pvp[]' placeholder='0.00' id='currency' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='0.00' required></td>

Comment: ok fiz umas alterações no seu código baseado no html e esta funcionando, vou editar a resposta.

Comment: certo. funciona usando class. agora uma pergunta... e se eu usar MULTIPLOS de <tr>... ele ja nao funciona, apenas no primeiro <tr> ehehe

Comment: tente dar um console.log(elements); provavelmente ele não deve estar encontrando os elementos, eu adicionei mais campos e coloquei um deles dentro de um <tr> e continua funcionando. veja se tem algum erro no console. vou adicionar o html que usei para os testes

Comment: ele funciona, mas isto deve ser erro meu, pois os <tr> adicionados nao sao REAIS, isto e, nao estao no codigo, o utilizador a que os Adiciona via Buttao.

Comment: entendi, então provavelmente não funciona porque quando o document.querySelector é executado esse <tr> ainda não existe, você poderia criar uma função(ou um método caso esteja trabalhando com OO)  e chamar a função após essa <tr> ser adicionada para também adicionar esse novo elemento na variável elements